# filter a column based on values of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c("1a", "1b", "2a", "2b", "3a", "4b", "5a", "5b"),
           Sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2))
```

```
 ID Sex
 1a   1
 1b   2
 2a   2
 2b   1
 3a   1
 4b   2
 5a   1
 5b   2
```

I want to filter based on `ID`. Specifically, if there are same numbers in a string in `ID`, such as 1a and 1b, 2a and 2b, and 5a and 5b, then I want to filter rows with `Sex` = 1. Additionally, I want to keep the rows with 3a and 4b, because it does not have its counterparts of 3b and 4a, regardless of its value in `Sex`.

My final desired output is:

```
 ID Sex
 1a   1
 2b   1
 3a   1
 4b   2
 5a   1
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may group by the numeric part of 'ID', and `filter` where `Sex` is 1 or (`|`) when number of rows is 1

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(grp = readr::parse_number(ID)) %>%
   filter(Sex == 1|n() ==1) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  ID      Sex
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1a        1
2 2b        1
3 3a        1
4 4b        2
5 5a        1
```

Answer (score 5):

Idea:

- split ID between number and letter to check whether there are several letters for each ID first number
- group by number
- keep when there's one letter max, or when ID_2 contains both "a" and "b" and Sex == 1

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(ID = c("1a", "1b", "2a", "2b", "3a", "4b", "5a", "5b"),
                   Sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2))

data %>% 
  separate(ID, into = c("ID_1", "ID_2"), sep = 1) %>% 
  group_by(ID_1) %>% 
  filter(n() <= 1 | (all(c("a", "b") %in% ID_2) & Sex == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unite(col = "ID", ID_1, ID_2, sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   ID      Sex
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 1a        1
#> 2 2b        1
#> 3 3a        1
#> 4 4b        2
#> 5 5a        1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  add_count(gsub("[a-z]", "", ID)) %>% 
  filter(Sex == 1 | n == 1) %>% 
  select(ID, Sex)

#>   ID Sex
#> 1 1a   1
#> 2 2b   1
#> 3 3a   1
#> 4 4b   2
#> 5 5a   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

data |> group_by(sub("\\D" , "" , ID)) |>
filter(n() == 1 | Sex == 1) |> ungroup() |>
select(ID , Sex)
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  ID      Sex
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1a        1
2 2b        1
3 3a        1
4 4b        2
5 5a        1
```

Answer (score 1):

One more similar to @akrun's solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(group_id = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", ID))) %>% 
  arrange(Sex, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group_id)
```

```
  ID      Sex
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1a        1
2 2b        1
3 3a        1
4 4b        2
5 5a        1
```